# wpf command control visibility

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, command

I have a custom command:

```
public static class CommandLibrary
{
    private static RoutedUICommand cmdMyCommand = new RoutedUICommand("My command", "MyCommand", typeof(CommandLibrary));
    public static RoutedUICommand MyCommand{ get { return cmdMyCommand ; } }
}
```

and I register a binding like this

```
CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(SomeClass), new CommandBinding(CommandLibrary.MyCommand, new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(myCommandExecuteHandler), new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(myCommandCanExecuteHandler)));
```

And in generic.xaml I have a Buton with Command property set. The button is being properly enabled/disabled based on logic in myCommandCanExecuteHandler.

But now I would like to also control this button's visibility (independent of CanExecute which is mapped to IsEnabled). How do I approach that problem?

A discussion about the same problem is available here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c20782f8-2d04-49d3-b822-f77b4b87c27a/, but somehow the idea that CanBeSeen is a property of RoutedUICommand derived class does not appeal to me.

Comment: Control visibility based on what exactly? On the command's executability?

Comment: Based on my custom logic which is to be different from command executability logic.

Answer (score 1):

you can bind the the visibility attribute in xaml to the value which decides button's visibility

```
<Button Content="Button" Height="23" Visibility="{Binding someclass, Converter={Binding VisibitlityConverter}}"/>
```

and use a converter to convert bool value to callpsed or visible

```
class visibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value == true? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: WPF already supplies a class for this purpose (BooleanToVisibilityConverter, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx). I don't think that's what the OP wants, however...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make the button to be visible when the button is enabled/disabled... If then you have to bind the IsEnabled property to Visibility property using the Boolean to Visibility converter...

Comment: No, it has to be "independent of CanExecute" (as indicated in the original question). In some cases I want to button to be visible even if it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem today.

"Sometimes" the CanExecute binding is being ignored when the visibility of the button is set collapsed state by the visibility converter. I said "sometimes" because, if I put a breakpoint in the visibility converter, it alters the behaviour.

When the visibility is changed to Visible - the CanExecute is not being called again. A mouse click anywhere on the UI refreshes the CanExecute binding, which makes it work as expected.

I worked around this issue by binding to the Button IsEnabled property directly to a property on my viewmodel, which reflects what my CanExecute does.